# Why won't the overlay go away? [react-native-modal-overlay]

Tags: react-native

I am trying to integrate an overlay function with my react-native app. I found a perfect npm module for it: [react-native-modal-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-overlay).

When I test the sample code the overlay appears, but doesn't go away when the outside is pressed. The documentation isn't the best, and in addition, it does not seems like I am the only one [who has faced this problem](https://github.com/rgabs/react-native-modal-overlay-example/issues/1).

Here is the sample code that a user [has provided](https://github.com/rgabs/react-native-modal-overlay-example/blob/master/index.ios.js):

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, Button
} from 'react-native';
import Overlay from 'react-native-modal-overlay';

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  state = {modalVisible: false}

  showOverlay() {
    this.setState({modalVisible: true})
  }

  hideOverlay() {
    this.setState({modalVisible: false})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Example: react-native-modal-overlay
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
        <Button
  onPress={this.showOverlay.bind(this)}
  title="Show Overlay"
  color="#841584"
/>

        <Overlay visible={this.state.modalVisible} closeOnTouchOutside animationType="zoomIn"
            containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(37, 8, 10, 0.78)'}} childrenWrapperStyle={{backgroundColor: '#eee'}} >
          <Text style={{fontWeight:'300', fontSize: 20}}>Some Overlay Heading</Text>
          <View style={{borderBottomWidth: 1, width: 100, paddingTop: 10}}></View>
          <Text style={{fontWeight:'300', fontSize: 16, paddingTop: 20, textAlign:'center'}}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo te novum tritani maiestatis. At libris reformidans mel, et modo idque pericula sit, alienum appareat cu eos. At pri tota nulla consequuntur. Est te diam erant, eum no altera dolorem facilisis. Ad per facilisi pericula postulant, id his dicta facete, alii constituto at per. Ex his alia graece democritum.
</Text>
        </Overlay>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Why doesn't the overlay go away when the outside is pressed?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and paste the code here, someone may be able to help you format it.

Comment: I added the code you referenced inside the question. Please have a look via the edit window so you can see how you can do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code on github seems to have some important code that your example above doesn't.  Namely, an onClose() function is defined:

`onClose = () => this.setState({ modalVisible: false});`

And the `<Overlay>` line also references onClose():

`<Overlay visible={this.state.modalVisible} onClose={this.onClose} closeOnTouchOutside>`